# css style for selector <tr> with asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have a table generated with ASP.NET GridView, and I have to put some space between each `<tr>`.

In my CSS file I have description for `<tr>` selector:

```
.tr {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

But, using developer tools in browser, I've founded that style for `<tr>` is used not from my CSS file, but it has "user defined stylesheet" and I can't change `margin-bottom` even in browser developer tools.

So, what is the problem?

Comment: `.tr` targets a class named "tr", it's likely you want to target `tr` which will match elements of type "tr".

Answer (score 2):

You've created a *class* selector named "tr" by prefixing the tag with a period, so you're not targeting the element itself, but any elements with `class="tr"`. Try dropping the `.`:

```
tr {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Beware, though, you might not want to affect every single `<tr>` in your site. Maybe you specify a special class on the `GridView` (`<asp:GridView CssClass="fatrows" />`) and then target its rows with slightly more specific CSS:

```
table.fatrows tr {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Or stick to the `GridView` conventions by specifying a special CSS class on its row items:

```
<asp:GridView>
    <RowStyle CssClass="fatrows" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And target the rows themselves:

```
tr.fatrows {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Obviously you'll want to come up with a more meaningful class name...

Answer (score 1):

What you have:

```
.tr /* incorrectly targets elements with the class "tr" */ { 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

What you need:

```
tr /* targets elements of type TR */ { 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```